# Start Activity from BroadcastReceiver only once using locks --Android

Tags: android, android-intent

**Scenario** :

When two alarms are set at the same time, then only of them should be shown.

**My Problem:**

I have a broadcastreceiver which forwards an intent to AlarmGoOffActivity when its time. However, I need to check if AlarmGoOffActivity is already running before forwarding an intent. From one of the answers I saw in SO. I tried this approach.Earlier, both alarms fired. Now, neither alarm fires now.

**Code**

***MyBroadCastReceiver.java***

```
 if (AlarmGoOffActivity.running) {
                   BLog("AlarmActivity running");

            } else {
                BLog("AlarmActivity  not running ");

                //set this variable true so that new broadcasts are not entertained
                AlarmGoOffActivity.running = true;

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmGoOffActivity.class);
                intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent1.putExtra(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, id);
                String ext = extras.getString(DBHelper.TASK_TITLE);
                if (ext != null) {
                    intent1.putExtra(DBHelper.TASK_TITLE, ext);
                }
                BLog("Starting alarm fire");
                context.startActivity(intent1);
            }
```

***AlarmGoOffActivity.java***

```
public class AlarmGoOffActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public static boolean running = false;
.....

 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();  
    //changing the lock to false here. So a new one can start from 
    //broadcastreceiver
    running = false;
    }
}
```

I was expecting the first one to fire. Now, neither one fires. Why is this not working? Is it because of the static variable (some concept I missed?) or is it because of the time gap of a 10 or less milliseconds between the broadcasts. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver should handle the intent and then exit quickly. It should not try to determine if the `Activity` is visible or active or whatever.

Instead, you should have the `Activity` handle re-notifications. In particular, you will probably find `onNewIntent` useful for processing new intents sent from the receiver. In your activity you can set flags to determine how to handle re-notifications versus the state the `Activity` is currently in.